# web service - client classes

Tags: java, web-services

The web service that I implemented is up and running, when I try to run the client I get the following error with regard to the classes that were generated using wsimport,

```
    Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://server.agency.hw2/}userJoined". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.UserJoined
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.ObjectFactory.createUserJoined(hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.UserJoined)
        at hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at ChatCompany.BackendChatServer.hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.UserJoined
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://server.agency.hw2/}userJoinedResponse". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.UserJoinedResponse
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.ObjectFactory.createUserJoinedResponse(hw2.chat.backend.main.generatedfromserver.UserJoinedResponse)
```

But I can't figure out what exactly is meant by the error. I am assuming I need to change something in annotations in these classes as pointed out by the compiler:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "userJoinedResponse")
public class UserJoinedResponse {


}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "userJoined", propOrder = {
    "arg0"
})
public class UserJoined {
```

could someone please point out why there's a name collision and what annotations I need to change?

thanks

Comment: Was all of the generated code produced in one execution of `wsimport`,  or several executions?

Comment: Err, what is meant by the number of executions of wsimport? I just ran the command through the Windows CMD once if this answers it.

Comment: Could you paste the annotations you used in the UserJoined class? Are you dealing with code you did not write yourself? If yes, do a search for 'name = "userJoinedResponse"' and 'name = "userJoined"' across all the code and see if you find the duplicate annotations.

Comment: these classes were generated using the wsimport tool, I only wrote the client's main class to run the web service client, here are the annotations in class UserJoined:
'

(how do I mark a text as code in comments? i tried adding a code tag but it doesn't work)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "userJoined", propOrder = {
    "arg0"
})
public class UserJoined {
'

I am not sure about what you mean by duplicate annotations, because for example the name value is different in both annotations, if you please can further explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teacher has suggested (among other reasons) that maybe there is something wrong with the way i ran the wsimport utility, so I regenerated the client class files using wsimport and the problem was solved. it might have been that I didn't specify the package name at the beginning and did it manually first time but I am uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception. The reason is a similarity of names both classes. When you have class with name `UserJoined` during wsdl generation process JAXB generate element with name `UserJoinedResponse` (see your wsdl file).

And the you try to add another class with the same name (`UserJoinedResponse`). So just rename `UserJoinedResponse` class or annotate it as mentioned in the exception.